# My Android Application is getting rejected from PlayStore

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, developer-console

I am uploading my application in the Android PlayStore and it is getting rejected because of **SMS permission** in it, but in my *Manifest.xml* file, there is **no SMS permission added**.

After having a conversation with the Google team they said that there is permission available of SMS and I am unable to find it.

Below is the screenshot provided by the Google Team and it has SMS permission in there.

[image: Screenshot shared by Google Team]

My Manifest file looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.msonline.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MSOAppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:label,android:theme">

//Other declarations of Activities

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any Help is appreciable thanks in Advance.

Edit #1

> build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 31
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                    multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation('com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'payumoney-sdk'
    }
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'


    implementation project(':libraryMobilePaymentSDKLive')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Manifest of Lib added

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.atom.library_mobilepaymentsdk"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="3.3" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/process"
    android:label="atom payment SDK"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
</application>
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file. Perhaps some of the dependencies add SMS permission.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. Google says to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`. Your manifest still doesn't have it. Why did you not add it?

Comment: @TheVee: I don't want to add the SMS permission as there is  no need of it now, and I did remove the permission from my Manifest file, but somehow it is displaying to the Google Team and because of it the application is getting rejected

Comment: @atarasenko : Question edited please review it

Comment: Please check manifest in final release apk. While creating final apk, gradle will merge manifests of app and libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third party libraries also contribute to your permission tree. In your case the below library that you are using is having `RECEIVE_SMS` declared in manifest.

```
com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0
```

You can check the sdk manifest from sdk's git repo using below this [link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/blob/master/sdkui/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).

There is RECEIVE_SMS defined in manifest.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

What you can try to do is to remove this permission, first declare in your manifest `tools:node="remove"` then add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

The final merged manifest will not have RECEIVE_SMS

Comment: This helped me, Please also add the below code which will remove the permission from the release build, so because of this code I don't need to contact the SDK Vendor
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS” tools:node=”remove” />

Answer (score 2):

Surely you are using a third party library that add this permission.
What you can try to do is to remove this permission, first declare in your manifest `tools:node="remove"` then add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

The final merged manifest will not have RECEIVE_SMS